# How to pass parameters to PivotTable filters on SharePoint Excel Services?

Tags: excel, rest, sharepoint

We're trying to provide users the ability to download a prepared Excel report from a SharePoint site. The template for the report, containing a PivotTable, will be present in a shared library. Users don't directly interact with Excel, but with webpages instead. Based on the user's filter selections on these webpages, an option to download a "prepared" report will be available.

The objective here is to pass the selected filter parameters to the Excel Services via REST on a URL call, and obtain the prepared workbook as a downloadable.

So far, we've been able to download the workbook as-is:
`http://server/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/PivotPOC.xlsx/Model?$format=workbook` -- this works.

The pivot filter value column is situated in Column B, so to pass filter values, we tried this:
`http://server/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/sites/test/Shared%20Documents/PivotPOC.xlsx/Model?Ranges('B1')=David&$format=workbook` -- **this doesn't work** -- and shows up this error on Firefox in the console:

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

***What is the right way to pass parameters to a PivotTable when using Excel Services?***

- How to pass simple strings and integers?
- How to pass values for multi-valued parameters? Comma separated?
- How to pass MDX members?
- Also, is there a query string length limit?